# Send email in python using subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess, postfix-mta

I wrote a script to retrieve weather report from a website and send it to my girfriend in the morning.

Using Gmail. Of course I can send it using my Postfix server. Here is the script.

What **I'm not sure is how to use Popen() function in the situation with so many arguments.**

I can send the mail using the command.

`$ mail -s "おお様からの天気予報" abc@gmail.com < foo`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import subprocess

weather_url = "http://www.weather.com.cn/weather/101020100.shtml"
f=urllib2.urlopen(weather_url)
html = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

content = soup.title.string

with open("foo","w") as mail:
    mail.write(content.encode('utf-8'))

command_line = 'mail -s "おお様からの天気予報" abc@gmail.com < foo'

li = command_line.split()

process = subprocess.Popen(li, shell=True)

returncode = process.wait()
```

The content of the weather report is in the `foo` file. Can somebody tell me how to use `Popen()` with so many arguments?

I tried a lot.

This script just doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass an argument list when you use `shell=True` you can just pass an argument string...

```
command_line = 'mail -s "おお様からの天気予報" abc@gmail.com < foo'
process = subprocess.Popen(command_line, shell=True)
```

Or.. you can not use the shell to interpret your arguments and pass a list...

```
command_line = 'mail -s "おお様からの天気予報" abc@gmail.com < foo'
li = command_line.split()
process = subprocess.Popen(li)
```

But you can't pass an argument list *and* use the shell to interpret it.

Based on the nature of your command, I would recommend passing a string to the shell to interpret. (the first option)

Comment: @caylus You are welcome to open a new question with what you have tried and link it as a comment here, I will try to look at it. But this is not the place.